# How to Handle the Session in Apache HttpClient 4.1

Tags: java, session, cookies, httpclient

I am using the HttpClient 4.1.1 to test my server's REST API.

I can manage to login seem to work fine but when I try to do anything else I am failing.

Most likely I have a problem setting the cookie in the next request.

Here is my code currently:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(<my server login URL>);
httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet)
sessionID = httpResponse.getFirstHeader("Set-Cookie").getValue();
httpGet.addHeader("Cookie", sessionID);
httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

Is there a better way to manage the session/cookies setting in the HttpClient package?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The correct way is to prepare a [`CookieStore`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/CookieStore.html) which you need to set in the [`HttpContext`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext.html) which you in turn pass on every [`HttpClient#execute()`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html#execute%28org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,%20org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext%29) call.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
httpContext.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
// ...

HttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(method1, httpContext);
// ...

HttpResponse response2 = httpClient.execute(method2, httpContext);
// ...
```

Comment: in case of session expired what happen ?

Comment: @Ankur, usually the server will notice that the session is expired and redirect you to a login page. If your request was read-only, it will redirect you to the page after successful auth, but if it was mutative you will have to do it again.